# Создание имени файла и запись текста в файл через консоль в java

Tags: java, файлы

Озадачился таким вопросом: как в java через консоль написать имя файла и текст файла, а потом сохранить его. Смог сделать просто запись текста в файл без консоли. Вот:

```
package ua.com.prologistic;

import java.io.*;
 
public class Program {
 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        try(FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("notes3.txt", false))
        {
            String text = "Hello world!";
            writer.write(text);
            writer.append('\n');
             
            writer.flush();
        }
        catch(IOException ex){
             
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        } 
    } 
}
```

> P.s. Нужно побольше обьяснений, крайне хочется узнать эту тему! Спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Program {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Введите имя файла: ");
        String fileName = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Введите контент: ");
        String content = sc.nextLine();
        save(fileName, content);        
    }

    private static void save(String fileName, String content) throws IOException {
        Files.write(Paths.get(fileName), content.getBytes());
    }

}
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!